# R folder paths, retrieve folder name

Tags: regex, r

I have a string like this

```
SERVER/MONTHLY/REPORT FOLDER NAME/REPORT.XLS
SERVER
SERVER/AD_HOC/REPORT FOLDER NAME/REPORT.XLS
SERVER/WEEKLY/MAIN FOLDER NAME/SUB FOLDER/REPORT NAME.XLS
SERVER/DAILY/REPORT FOLDER NAME/REPORT.XLS
```

I want a unique list of the REPORT FOLDER NAMEs

I have a variable type folders which contains all this information

```
folders <- list.dirs(path="foo", full.names=F, recursive=TRUE)
folders.split <- strsplit(folders, "/")
```

Its from this point on im a bit stuck because i think it involves Regex

Basically all the folders that have DAILY,MONTHLY,WEEKLY,AD-HOC in their folder path i want to be able to pull the REPORT FOLDER NAME from it which will always be directly after it

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not completely wrong with my regular expression, and if I understood you right, this might work:

```
folders <- c("SERVER/AD_HOC/REPORT FOLDER NAME/REPORT.XLS",
            "SERVER/WEEKLY/MAIN FOLDER NAME/SUB FOLDER/REPORT NAME.XLS",
            "SERVER/DAILY/REPORT FOLDER NAME/REPORT.XLS")

basename(substr(folders, 0, regexpr("/[^/]*$", folders)))
```

returns

```
[1] "REPORT FOLDER NAME" "SUB FOLDER"         "REPORT FOLDER NAME"
```

i.e. you get the last folder name in your path.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your quick response. This answer wont cover what I'm looking for. In example 2, your script will return SUB FOLDER but I need REPORT FOLDER NAME. I also want the end result in a Table format so that i can merge the results with another data set i have...thanks again for your time

Comment: Ok, got it. But what if the folder does not contain a REPORT FOLDER NAME? How do you know whether there is such a name or not? I assume that REPORT FOLDER NAME is a place holder for varying folder names, depending on the report name? If there's a speciifc pattern, the regular expression may be adapted accordingly. Converting the return value into a table format should be less problematic, it's just a question of how this table should look like?

Comment: Yep...it will always be preceded by either DAILY/ or MONTHLY/ or WEEKLY/ or AD-HOC/ so for example DAILY/REPORT FOLDER NAME